# await not working for insert command in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have an array of addons and I want to insert them into the db table.

```
var addons = [sample,sample,.....]

return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    addons.foEach(async addon => {

        // first check if the items is in db
        const response = await Kinex.where({}).from('table_name');

        if(response.length == 0){
            // insert new record
            const insertResp = kinex('table_name').insert(addon)
            addon.system_id = insertResp[0];
        }else{
            addon.system_id = response[0].id;
        }
    })
})
```

What I expected is to have unique record in the database, but the above code produced duplicate record in the database. Please help to find out the issue with the code.

Comment: Since you are passing an asynchronous function to `addons.forEach`, each element is kind of processed in parallel. `await` does work. But `forEach` doesn't know about asynchronous functions.

Comment: I would create a new Promise for each 'addon' opeartion, and use `Promise.all`

Comment: Fixing foreach won't fix the issue if this is called from a cluster on an app server. Still, two threads will read, find nothing and insert. You need a DB constraint to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is running `async` function inside a loop. As mentioned by @Felix, `forEach` doesn't know about async functions and doesn't wait for your where query to return. If you wanna do things in async manner inside loops, you can do it with `for..of` loops. Also make sure to always use `try/catch` blocks while using `async/await`. Below is the code in your case:

```
const addons = [sample,sample,.....];
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        for (let addon of addons) {
            // first check if the items is in db
            const response = await Kinex.where({}).from('table_name');
            if (response.length) {
                const insertResp = await kinex('table_name').insert(addon)
                addon.system_id = insertResp[0];
            } else addon.system_id = response[0].id;
            resolve(); // resolve with whatever you wants to return 
        }
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e)
    }
});
```

You can read more on `for..of` with `async/await` [here](https://lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795/).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @Sándor, here's the code using `Promise.all`:

```
var addons = [sample, sample, .....]
return Promise.all(addons.map(async addon => {
    // Do your async stuff here

    // first check if the items is in db
    const response = await Kinex.where({}).from('table_name');

    if (response.length == 0) {
        // insert new record
        const insertResp = kinex('table_name').insert(addon)
        addon.system_id = insertResp[0];
    } else {
        addon.system_id = response[0].id;
    }
}))
```