# Program doesn't await async function before continuing flow

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

In the following code, the csv2pg function is async

```
const postUsages = async (req: MulterRequest, res: Response, next: any) => {
  try {
    const result = await csv2pg(req, next);

    res.status(200).json({
      msg: 'File uploaded/import successfully!',
      file: req.file,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      msg: 'File uploaded/import failed!',
      file: req.file,
    });
  }
};
```

The problem is, the await doesn't seem to await the function being finished before returning the res.status(200)

Here is the content of the csv2pg function that is being called (the async bit in this code is the forEach and the pool.query)

```
const csv2pg = (req: MulterRequest, next: any): any => {
  let provider_id = req.body!.provider_id;

  const filePath = appRoot + '/reports/' + req.file.filename;

  const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  const csvData: any[] = [];

  const csvStream = csv
    .parse()
    .on('data', (data: any) => {
      csvData.push(data);
    })
    .on('error', (err: any) => {
      throw err.message;
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      csvData.shift();
      csvData.forEach((row) => {
        pool.query(
          `INSERT INTO usage (date_and_time, consumption, reading_quality, provider_id)
            VALUES ((TO_TIMESTAMP($1, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Melbourne')::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, $2, $3, ${provider_id})`,
          row,
          (err: any) => {
            if (err) {
              next(new Error(err));
            }
          }
        );
      });
      fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
    });
  stream.pipe(csvStream);
};
```

Another problem with this is that when there's an issue, there's another error message on top saying that the headers were already set (of course, the server already returned to the client by that time)

Ideally, when an error is raised, the whole function should stop, return the error message, and wait for new incoming requests

Comment: the problem is running async code inside forEach loop, Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63618100/11531708

Comment: your csv2pg function is a time-consuming function. so you better use a promise. guessing resolve will solve your problem.

Comment: @MohammedAmirAnsari This only solve the problem partly as the poo.query is another async function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to wait for `csv2pg` to finish all async operations, it must return a promise. Since the async actions are in a loop, we have to use `Promise.all`. Try this:

```
const csv2pg = (req: MulterRequest, next: any): any => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let provider_id = req.body.provider_id;

    const filePath = appRoot + "/reports/" + req.file.filename;

    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    const csvData: any[] = [];

    const csvStream = csv
      .parse()
      .on("data", (data: any) => {
        csvData.push(data);
      })
      .on("error", (err: any) => {
        reject(err.message);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        csvData.shift();
        const promisesArray = csvData.map((row) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            pool.query(
              `INSERT INTO usage (date_and_time, consumption, reading_quality, provider_id)
              VALUES ((TO_TIMESTAMP($1, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Melbourne')::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, $2, $3, ${provider_id})`,
              row,
              (err: any) => {
                if (err) {
                  reject(new Error(err));
                } else {
                  resolve();
                }
              }
            )
          );
        });

        Promise.all(promisesArray).then(() => {
          fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
          resolve();

        })
      });
    stream.pipe(csvStream);
  });
};
```

Please note, I also wrapped your `pool.query` in a promise, since this function doesn't return a promise by default.

Comment: The code doesn't start with that solution. Running nodemon, it says `[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart`

Comment: What do you mean? All I did was change `csv2pg`'s implementation. That cant affect whether your code runs or not.

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be that you are using this code inside the for-loop. Using **Promise.all** would fix the problem. I would recommend this post to you: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/promise-all-in-javascript-with-example-6c8c5aea3e32/.

It explains everything in detail.